# Binary tree doesn't inserting

Tags: c++, binary-tree, abstract-class

I have to write a collection - binary tree, using polymorphism. Its' roots must be objects of abstract class. I have class Node and Btree, but function "add" doesn't work correct. What am I doing wrong..? Help pls

```
class Node {
public:
    Node() {
        o = nullptr;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    Node(object* obj) {
        o = obj;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    friend class Btree;
private:
    object *o;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
class Btree {
public:
Btree() {
    count = 0;
    root = nullptr;
}
void deleteNotes(Node *n) {
    if (!n) return;
    delete n;
    delete n->left;
    delete n->right;
}
Node* getRoot() {
    return root;
}
Node* getLeft(Node* n) {
    return n->left;
}
Node* getRight(Node* n) {  
    return n->right;
}
object* getData(Node *n) {
    return n->o;
}
void add(object *obj) {
    Node *n = new Node;
    n->o = obj;
    if (!n) {
        return;
    }
    insertNode(root, n);
}
void insertNode(Node *node, Node *elem) {
    if (node == nullptr) node = elem;
    else {
        if (equal(node->o, elem->o) < 0) 
            insertNode(node->left, elem);
        else insertNode(node->right, elem);
    }
}
Node *search(object *obj) {
    return searchNode(root, obj);
}
Node *searchNode(Node *node, object *obj) {
    if (equal(node->o, obj) == 0) return node;
    else {
        if (equal(node->o, obj) < 0) {
            searchNode(node->left, obj);
        }
        else {
            searchNode(node->right, obj);
        }
    }
}
void show() {
    showNode(root);
}
void showNode(Node *n) {
    if (n != nullptr) {
        showNode(n->left);
        cout << n->o->uploadInString() << "\n";
        showNode(n->right);
    }
}
void deleteNodes(Node *n) {
    if (!n) return;
    delete n;
    delete n->left;
    delete n->right;
}
~Btree() {
    deleteNodes(root);
}
private:
int count;
Node *root;
};
```

I have two datatypes - Integer and Date as children of class "object". I dont't know which details should I write........

Comment: *"doesn't work correct."* -- this covers the case where the `add` function causes a surge in volcanic eruptions around the world. In other words, this description is useless. Why do you believe it doesn't work? What are the symptoms? If it's not a compile-time error or a crash, what are the expected and actual results for a simple test case?

Comment: *"I dont't know which details should I write"* -- you should write enough details so that someone can copy the code from your question, feed that code to a compiler, and reproduce your result. You should also strive for the minimum amount of code that is sufficient. (This is known as a [mre].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
void insertNode(Node *node, Node *elem) {
  if (node == nullptr) node = elem;
  else {
  ...
  }
}
```

The first time you try to add a node, `node` is equal to `root`, and so it is equal to `nullptr`. So this function sets `node` equal to `elem`, and then quits. *But `node` is a local variable, it belongs to the function.* The function modifies the value of the variable, then the function quits and the variable is forgotten. The value of `root` is still `nullptr`.

There are several ways to solve this problem. Here is one:

```
Node* insertNode(Node *node, Node *elem) {
  if (node == nullptr) return elem;

  if (equal(node->o, elem->o) < 0)
    node->left = MyInsertNode(node->left, elem);
  else node->right = MyInsertNode(node->right, elem);

  return node;
}

void add(object *obj) {
  ...
  root = insertNode(root, n);
}
```

There are other problems. I advise you to work on simpler exercises (such as linked lists) for a while longer, before attempting trees.